# Autoselect dropdown dependant on another dropdown and vice versa with hundreds of entries

Tags: jquery, html-select

I am a newbie programmer and this is my very 1st question on stackoverflow, so apologise if the question sounds a bit too basic for your level.

Refer to my JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azzaeff/ug1eo5rp/

```
$('select[id=scholarid]').change(function(event) {
    var scholarids = $(this).val();
    if (scholarids == 'A001')
        $('select[id=scholarname]').val('Derrick B. Bailey');
    else if (scholarids == 'A002')
        $('select[id=scholarname]').val('Amber J. Holt');
    else if (scholarids == 'A003')
        $('select[id=scholarname]').val('Tracy B. Serrano');
});

$('select[id=scholarname]').change(function(event) {
    var scholarnames = $(this).val();
    if (scholarnames == 'Derrick B. Bailey')
        $('select[id=scholarid]').val('A001');
    else if (scholarnames == 'Amber J. Holt')
        $('select[id=scholarid]').val('A002');
    else if (scholarnames == 'Tracy B. Serrano')
        $('select[id=scholarid]').val('A003');
});
```

You can see that I have created an autoselect 'Scholar' dropdown based on another dropdown, 'Scholar ID'. Example:, change the ID to A003 will change the name dropdown to Tracy B. Serrano. The vice-versa also works, that is, changing the name dropdown will also change his/her assigned IDs. Example, change the name to Derrick B. Bailey will change his IDs to A001.

This works flawlessly. But as you can see, this example is only just use 3 names/ids.

Personally, I am ok if I have to write dropdowns for, say 10 or maybe 20 names/ids, but now there are hundreds of combination of ids and names. I think it is not very viable to repeatedly write 'if-else' combinations hundreds of times. I think there should be a better way to write, say, using arrays or such. But I personally could not find a way to do this, or search it.

If anyone can help write simplified code for hundreds of entries, I would be very much appreciated. Or if there's already similar answers to this here in this forum or any forum, you may point it out as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application logic look weird to me. If it is one to one mapping, why don't you just have one select and let user select the name instead? Anyway, there are many ways you can archive this but first, you have to plan how you want to store your 100 or 1000 records. Since what I can see now is one to one, the easier way is using selected index as below:

```js
$("#s1").change(function(){
  $("#s2 option").eq($(this).prop("selectedIndex")).prop("selected", "selected");
});

$("#s2").change(function(){
  $("#s1 option").eq($(this).prop("selectedIndex")).prop("selected", "selected");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="s1">
  <option value="A001">A001</option>
  <option value="A002">A002</option>
  <option value="A003">A003</option>
</select>

<select id="s2">
  <option value="John">John</option>
  <option value="Calvin">Calvin</option>
  <option value="Mark">Mark</option>
</select>
```

If somehow your data cannot use index to map, use something like below:

```js
$("#s1").change(function(){
  $("#s2 option[data-mapping=" + $(this).val() + "]").prop("selected", "selected");
});

$("#s2").change(function(){
  $("#s1").val($(this).find(":selected").data("mapping"));
});

$("#s1").trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="s1">
  <option value="A001">A001</option>
  <option value="A002">A002</option>
  <option value="A003">A003</option>
</select>

<select id="s2">
  <option value="John" data-mapping='A002'>John</option>
  <option value="Calvin" data-mapping='A003'>Calvin</option>
  <option value="Mark" data-mapping='A001'>Mark</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Chong, this is exactly what I needed! In fact, I like your second suggestion as well (using data-mapping), this means that I do not need to order the names/ids alphabetically.

Comment: About your question, yes its true I can just use only one select with both ids and names combined in the options list ie. "A001 - Derrick B. Bailey" but the reason I split it to two select options is more to my personal aesthetic. Also, there are users who remembers someone's ID but does not remember his/her name, and vice-versa.By splitting it, user can directly use the appropriate select option (whether by Ids or name). Thanks again!